# discord.js store argument data in a file with the name + guild id

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Alright, so basically, I am using File System in order to grab the user input, create a file with the inputted name, and store it in a specific folder. However, I am unable to get the guild.id and combine it with the name of the file the user made.

Basically, what I want it to do is when you run the `createchar (name)` command, it creates a file with the name plus the guild id, so basically `createchar test` would result in a .txt file being created named `testguildID`. This is so that the command can work on many different servers.

This also applies to `editchar` as well.

However, when I run the command, the command doesn't work, nor do I get an error in the console.

Here's the code:

```
client.on("message", message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if(command === "createchar") {

      fs.writeFile(`./characters/${args + guild.id}.txt`, 'utf8', function (err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          message.reply('Character created successfully.');
          console.log('File created successfully.');
      });
  }


if(command === "editchar") {
    fs.readFileSync(`./characters/${args[0] + guild.id}.txt`, 'utf8');


    var data = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(`${args}`));

    fs.writeFile(`./characters/${args[0] + guild.id}.txt`, data, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;;
message.reply('Character information edited successfully');
    console.log('File edited successfully');
})
}

if(command === "char") {
    var char = fs.readFileSync(`./characters/${args[0]}.txt`, 'utf8');
    var char3 = char.replace(`${args[0]}`, '');
    message.channel.send(">>>" + char3.replace(/,/g, " "));
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `message.` to `guild.id`, so thats the problem :)

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if(command === "createchar") {

      fs.writeFile(`./characters/${args + message.guild.id}.txt`, 'utf8', function (err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          message.reply('Character created successfully.');
          console.log('File created successfully.');
      });
  }


if(command === "editchar") {
    fs.readFileSync(`./characters/${args[0] + message.guild.id}.txt`, 'utf8');


    var data = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(`${args}`));

    fs.writeFile(`./characters/${args[0] + message.guild.id}.txt`, data, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;;
message.reply('Character information edited successfully');
    console.log('File edited successfully');
})
}

if(command === "char") {
    var char = fs.readFileSync(`./characters/${args[0]}.txt`, 'utf8');
    var char3 = char.replace(`${args[0]}`, '');
    message.channel.send(">>>" + char3.replace(/,/g, " "));
}
});
```